# when trying to set Capabilities on Chrome Options it is not listing .setCapability method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[.setCapability not listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fRgC.jpg)When trying to set Capability on chromeoption object set capability is not available and even if wrote it it give me and error.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: what error do you get? I checked - there are a lot of variants with `setCapability()` method.

Comment: Check the attached snapshot please, there is none of them.

Comment: Did anyone resolved this issue. I am also seeing in my code setup. I have imported both chrome.ChromeOptions and remote.CapabilityType. Still i am not seeing setCapbility() listed for the chromeOptions object. I need to set some proxy setup in my browser and i am using Selenium 3.5.3. Please answer anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Add Arguments rather than set capability if you are working in c# like below

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArguments(CapabilityType.AcceptInsecureCertificates, "true");
```

Or for Java  (Note: use below in side the method) and import -> import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, "true");
```

Comment: Already tried that before asking, but it didn't work for me..thank you